# How to integrate Google lens in my app?

Tags: android, google-goggles

I want to integrate google lens services into my android application, but I am not getting any straight forward approach to implement it, neither any library nor any Google API's. 
Any one can help me to implement google lens into my android app. If there is any way to call Google Goggles API's, then that is also fulfill my requirement up to an extend.

Comment: try below page.
"How to Use the Google Cloud Vision API in Android Apps"
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-google-cloud-vision-api-in-android-apps--cms-29009

Comment: Thanks Heejae, for your response, but Google cloud vision API's are not providing feature like Google Lens...

Comment: @sumeet did you find anything? I am currently looking into this as well.

Comment: @sumeet were you able to implement this, I'm also currently looking to implement it in my app. Please share.

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution.
Google has recently launched a new library to access the google lens service. I have implemented it into my app and it is working fine.
Here is the link to the library: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/lens
It is very easy to implement and less code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't integrate Google Lens into your Android App. But Google provides an ML kit supported by android that you can integrate into your app.

The ML Kit provides many Vision and NLP APIs that can help you make your own Google-like Lens.

**You can check some samples [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit)**

For more [checkout](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit)

---

### The ML kit includes:

**Vision APIs**

```
 - Barcode scanning
 - Face detection
 - Image labeling
 - Object detection and tracking
 - Text recognition
 - Digital Ink Recognition
 - Pose detection
 - Selfie segmentation
```

**NLP APIs**

```
 - Language ID
 - On-device translation
 - Smart Reply
 - Entity Extraction
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct implementation of Google Lens inside your apps.

However, there are a few alternatives like the Firebase MLKit : https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit.

It will help you with the essential features like:

```
Text Recognition
Face Detection
Barcode Scanning
Image Labeling
Landmark Recognition.
```